# sql SYNTAX for making date range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have some customers, which have visited my site in some of days, i want to make online and offline days for the customer as ranges. i have something like this:

```
A , 2017-01-10
A , 2017-01-17
A , 2017-01-18
B , 2017-01-15
B , 2017-01-16
B , 2017-01-17
B , 2017-01-20
B , 2017-01-21
```

and i want something like this:

```
A , 2017-01-10 , 2017-01-10 , 1
A , 2017-01-10 , 2017-01-17 , 0
A , 2017-01-17 , 2017-01-18 , 1
B , 2017-01-15, 2017-01-17, 1
B , 2017-01-17, 2017-01-20, 0
B , 2017-01-20, 2017-01-21, 1
```

Would you help me?

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: would you explain the logic of converting?

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the most important part of your post. An explanation of what you want. I am guessing you want to find groups of contiguous days? Maybe this will help. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/

Comment: Column headers?

Answer (score 0):

as the community in the comments said: there is really little information given, and the date 2017-01-16 for customer "B" is missing ;-)

However here is some sample-code how you maybe could achieve some similar reports:

```
CREATE TABLE VISITS
(
 Customer varchar(10)
,DateVisit datetime
)

INSERT INTO VISITS VALUES
 ('A' , '20170110')
,('A' , '20170117')
,('A' , '20170118')
,('B' , '20170115')
,('B' , '20170116')
,('B' , '20170117')
,('B' , '20170120')
,('B' , '20170121')


;WITH cte as (
SELECT Customer, DateVisit, LAG(DateVisit,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY DateVisit) AS Last_DateVisit
FROM VISITS
)
SELECT 
 Customer
,DateVisit as OnlineDate
,Last_DateVisit as LastOnlineDate
,CASE WHEN a.Last_DateVisit IS NULL
     THEN 'First Visit ever :-)'
     ELSE cast(DATEDIFF(DAY,Last_DateVisit, DateVisit) as varchar) + ' Days since LastVisit'
     END AS Note
FROM cte as a

-- your sql server version does not support lag? try this:
;WITH cte as (
SELECT Customer, DateVisit,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY DateVisit) as RowN
FROM VISITS
)
SELECT 
 a.Customer
,a.DateVisit as OnlineDate
,b.DateVisit as LastOnlineDate
,CASE WHEN b.DateVisit IS NULL
     THEN 'First Visit ever :-)'
     ELSE cast(DATEDIFF(DAY,b.DateVisit, a.DateVisit) as varchar) + ' Days since LastVisit'
     END AS Note
FROM cte as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte as b
on a.Customer = b.Customer
and a.RowN = b.RowN+1
```

OUTPUT

```
Customer | OnlineDate | LastOnlineDate | Note
---------+------------+----------------+-----------------------
A        | 2017-01-10 | NULL           | First Visit ever :-)
A        | 2017-01-17 | 2017-01-10     | 7 Days since LastVisit
A        | 2017-01-18 | 2017-01-17     | 1 Days since LastVisit
B        | 2017-01-15 | NULL           | First Visit ever :-)
B        | 2017-01-16 | 2017-01-15     | 1 Days since LastVisit
B        | 2017-01-17 | 2017-01-16     | 1 Days since LastVisit
B        | 2017-01-20 | 2017-01-17     | 3 Days since LastVisit
B        | 2017-01-21 | 2017-01-20     | 1 Days since LastVisit
```

I hope this code gives you some ideas how to get your solution or to concretise your question(s).

Regards
tgr